# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value in laravel 8 with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i have made a website where people can upload a picture, in the dev database the website works like it should, only if i upload my application and use the online database it gives this
error. i dont know how to solve this issue, because my code looks good from what i have read on the internet.

error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `image_gallery` (`image`, `title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1604249844.jpg, test, 2020-11-01 16:57:24, 2020-11-01 16:57:24))
```

my controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\ImageGallery;

class ImageGalleryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Listing Of images gallery
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::get();
        return view('tekeningen',compact('images'));
    }


    /**
     * Upload image function
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:8048',
        ]);


        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);


        $input['title'] = $request->title;
        ImageGallery::create($input);


        return back()
            ->with('success','De tekening is geupload!');
    }


    /**
     * Remove Image function
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        ImageGallery::find($id)->delete();
        return back()
            ->with('success','Image removed successfully.');
    }
}
```

and my migration looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateImageGalleryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('image_gallery', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('image_gallery');
    }
}
```

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ImageGallery extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'image_gallery';

    protected $fillable = ['title','image','id'];
}
```

And i have run migrate:fresh.

Comment: in your migration file -> `$table->bigIncrements('id')->(1);` what is `->(1)` ?

Comment: maybe he's trying to use "->from($integer)"

Comment: Your migration is wrong, change that to `$table->bigIncrements('id');` or `$table->id();`

Comment: @sta i have changed it but still it is giving me the same error!

Comment: @s.wadhwa i tried to set a default value that could be changed, because the error says it does't have a default value.

Comment: @MarijnBoeve After editing your migration as other fellows told you, you should reset your table by running php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: @AliAli i have run that command every time i have changed something. and still it is giving that error.

Comment: On your create method you are not passing the $uuid

Comment: @StevenPss how would i do that properly?

Comment: @MarijnBoeve delete the "id" from the $fillable array, the id should auto-increment and it doesn't have a default value unless you still have a table structure error.